# Cascaded Windows Plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a 2D objective function that evolves over time, I want to represent it in series of cascaded snapshots as layers in the following image:

[image]

I am not looking strictly for the image as above but a close representation. Is it possible in python using Matplotlib or other library? I have a 3D spline that shall pass through all these layers and hence I need to show them in cascaded figures.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this [script](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.py) in the page that @Junuxx refers, making:

```
ys = np.repeat(3,len(xs))
```

instead of

```
ys = np.random.rand(len(xs))
```

and adding this:

```
ax.set_axis_off()
```

Consequently:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')


def cc(arg):
    return mcolors.to_rgba(arg, alpha=0.6)

xs = np.arange(0, 10, 0.4)
verts = []
zs = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
for z in zs:
    ys = np.repeat(3,len(xs))
    ys[0], ys[-1] = 0, 0
    verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))

poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=[cc('r'), cc('g'), cc('b'),cc('y')])
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='y')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 10)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 4)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

gives this result:
[image]

I think you can achieve what you want with a little more changes

Comment: Probably it is a good idea to copy all the relevant code (with proper attribution) to this post. Code can be modified or the file renamed. This would make it impossible for future readers to understand the answer.

Comment: I agree with @JohanC, it shall be good idea to update the answer with the relevant code.